# How can i change my wishlist page title in MAGENTO?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am facing problaem in magento in change page title in wish list page. But I am not able to change page title. So, please anybodya can help me to set this wishlist page title.

Comment: Show some screenshots to clearify what are you exactly talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Magento sets most page titles in the layouts. Wishlist's can be found in `wishlist.xml`.

```
<wishlist_index_index translate="label">
       ...
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="wishlist/view.phtml">
                <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                    <title>My Wishlist</title>
                </action>
        </reference>
      ...
</wishlist_index_index>
```

So to change this, include this section in a local layout update file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <wishlist_index_index translate="label">
        <reference name="customer.wishlist">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                <title>New title here</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </wishlist_index_index>
</layout>
```